# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘void’

Tags: c++, class

so I keep getting this error while trying to compile the .cc file of a class. Here is my .cc code and the .hh code:

.hh:

```
#ifndef BINTREE_IO_PARINT_HH
#define BINTREE_IO_PARINT_HH


#include "BinTree.hh"
#include "ParInt.hh"
#include <iostream>

void read_bintree_parint(BinTree<ParInt>& a);

void write_bintree_parint(const BinTree<ParInt>& a); 

#endif
```

.cc:

```
#include "BinTreeIOParInt.hh"


void read_bintree_parint(BinTree<ParInt>& a){

    ParInt x;

    BinTree<ParInt> a1;
    BinTree<ParInt> a2;

    x.llegir();

    if(x.primer() != 0 and x.segon() != 0){

        read_bintree_parint(a1);
        read_bintree_parint(a2);
        a.BinTree(x, a1, a2);

    }


}

void write_bintree_parint(const BinTree<ParInt>& a){

    ParInt x;
    if(not a.empty()){
      BinTree<ParInt> a1 = a.left();
      BinTree<ParInt> a2 = a.right();

      x = a.value();

      write_bintree_parint(a1);
      cout<<" ";
      x.escriure();

      write_bintree_parint(a2);
      a.BinTree(x, a1, a2);
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is this one:

```
> BinTreeIOParInt.cc:4:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘void’
 void read_bintree_parint(BinTree<ParInt>& a){
```

If someone knows what's happening please explain.

Thank you all

Comment: Probably some manner of syntax error in one of the included headers.

Comment: What does `a.BinTree(x, a1, a2);` do?

Comment: What is in the other two header files.

Answer (score 0):

My glass ball says that you forgot to put a semicolon at the end of ParInt.hh. You might want to provide the source for those two headers, because it's pretty hard to debug without them.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `#include …` the compiler pasts the content of the file in place of the `#inculde` (well almost, there are some subtle things involving line numbers and filenames, but you can ignore them).

As you sometimes get error messages for a line below where the error is. This can also happen with `#include`, the error is probably in one of the included files.